# Asymptotic holonomic

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-equations, asymptotics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let 
$$f_{d}(h):=\sum_{k=1}^{d}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k-1}e^{d(k-\frac{d+1}{2})h} . $$ 
We claim that $ F(x):=\sum_{d=1}f_{d}\frac{x^{d}}{d!}$ is not holonomic???

I want to prove that above thing. Which I believe is true.(??) The following facts I give to support my statement. Still, I don't conclude it.

Now I know the following fact 
$exp(exp(h)x-1)=\sum_{d=1}exp(h)\frac{x^d}{d!}   \in \mathbb{C}(h)[[x]]$ is not holonomic.

Also, I noticed that $\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(h)}{e^{(d-1)/2}h}\rightarrow  \pm 1$. So each coefficent of $[x^d]F(x)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $e^{\frac{(d-1)}{2}h}$. Now using the fact can I conclude that $F(x)$ is not holonomic?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient $f_d(h)$ grows too quickly for $F(x)$ to be holonomic. Though irrelevant to this argument, note also that by the binomial theorem, 
  $$ f_d(h) = -e^{\frac  {-d(d+1)h}{2}}(1-e^{dh})^{d-1}. $$

Comment: Is there any theorem referring about the growth of the coefficient and holonomic?

Comment: I don't know where this is written down, but since the coefficients satisfy a linear recurrence with polynomial coefficients, they cannot grow faster than $d!^m$ for some constant $m$.